# How can I add mulitple columns and display maximum value?

Tags: mysql

In the following code, I am adding Fanbase, coach, TeamRanks, Organization and Kicker from Ranks table. It returns sum of each row as total. However, I am not sure, how I can display maximum value for total. I don't need the whole list of addition.

```
Select
  ID, 
  (Fanbase + Coach + TeamRanks + Organization + Kicker) as total,
  Fanbase, 
  Coach, 
  TeamRanks,
  Organization,
  Kicker
from Ranks;
```

This returns total for each column, however I need max. value of total.

```
Team     Fanbase    Coach    TeamRanks    Organization     Kicker


Chargers  80         60       29           18               10
Patriots  100       100       32           32               20
RAMS      80        90        30           25               23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way you can do this (and without deriving away too much from your original query), you can use `ORDER BY DESC` and `LIMIT`.

```
-- Assuming that ID=teamname
SELECT ID FROM
(SELECT
  ID, 
  (Fanbase + Coach + TeamRanks + Organization + Kicker) AS total
FROM Ranks ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 1) r;
```

**UPDATE:** I had one query in mind but I was afraid that it might not work in some MySQL version but just now I had time to try it and it seems to be working fine on MySQL 5.5, 5.6, 5.7 & 8.0. This query is much shorter and without using sub-query:

```
SELECT ID
FROM ranks 
ORDER BY  (Fanbase + Coach + TeamRanks + Organization + Kicker) DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

And also I would like to point out that if one of the column contains NULL value for all of the teams; for example if all of the `Kicker` value is NULL, this query doesn't seem to work. I've check the mathematical formula, if (Fanbase + Coach + TeamRanks + Organization + Kicker) = (10+ 10+ 20+ 30+ NULL) it will return NULL instead of 70. You could add function like `IFNULL(field,0)`. Like for example;

```
SELECT ID
FROM ranks 
ORDER BY (IFNULL(Fanbase,0)+IFNULL(Coach,0)+IFNULL(TeamRanks,0)+IFNULL(Organization,0)+IFNULL(Kicker,0)) DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

However, the best approach is of course to make your field at default `0` and `NOT NULL`. Here I'm just concerned about `What if ... ?`

Comment: @The Impaler both codes returned correctly rows associated with Max value of (Fanbase + Coach + TeamRanks + Organization + Kicker). However I want the query to display only the team name, not the entire rows of information associated with that team. This code displayed values for team, Total, Fanbase, Coach, TeamRanks, organizations and Kicker correctly, however I just want only the team name should be displayed.

Comment: @sul , if like that, make this as a sub-query - updated in my answer. ;)

Comment: Thank you guys! I really appreciate it. The query is returning what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MAX()` function to aggregate columns. For example:

```
Select
  MAX(Fanbase + Coach + TeamRanks + Organization + Kicker) as max_total
from Ranks;
```

**EDIT**: To get the data of teams with the `max_total` value, you can do:

```
Select
  ID, 
  (Fanbase + Coach + TeamRanks + Organization + Kicker) as total,
  Fanbase, 
  Coach, 
  TeamRanks,
  Organization,
  Kicker
from Ranks
where Fanbase + Coach + TeamRanks + Organization + Kicker = (
  Select
    MAX(Fanbase + Coach + TeamRanks + Organization + Kicker) as max_total
  from Ranks
)
```

This query will return all the teams in first position, in case there are multiple ones.

Comment: I am pretty new with MySQL. For this project I am trying to display the max value which your code solved it, however I am also trying to display team name with this max value. I tried this, but it complaints about invalid group use.

Comment: Select team from Ranks where (Max(Fanbase + Coach + TeamRanks + Organization + Kicker));

Comment: I see the following code works displaying both Max value and team, but I want only team name not the max value. Select team, max(Fanbase + Coach + TeamRanks + Organization + Kicker) as max_total from Ranks;

Comment: @sul Happy to help. Can you provide some sample data and the expected result? A few rows will go a long way to understand exactly what you need.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I have the following table. I am trying to add Fanbase, Coach, TeamRanks, Organization and return the max value associated with the Team. For example in the table below, I want to add Fanbase, Coach, TeamRanks and Organization value and return the team name that has max value. If Patriot has max value (Fanbase+Coach+TeamRanks+Organization) then display Patriots, other display any other team that has max value.

Comment: I am trying to add my table but it doesn't let me.

Comment: Use the edit button on the question and paste the data, or a link to imgur. I can format it.

Comment: Added a sample of the table is added in the question section. In this table it should add Fanbase, Coach, TeamRanks, Organization and Kicker for each team then it should return the team name that has the maximum value. In this case it will be Patriots.

Comment: @sul Added the query you wanted.

Comment: Thank you very much. Appreciate it.